# Gear ratio from speed and rpm

Tags: clutch, obd-ii, gears

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017271/obdii-determine-gear-given-speed-and-rpm

Referring to the above link, one method to find the current gear ratio is to calculate Speed/rpm (The rpm is the engine rpm). But say the clutch slips or transmission slips, how can I correctly determine which gear I am driving, and detect a clutch slip? Because if the clutch slips, the velocity is less that I get and hence speed/rpm decreases, thus implying I am driving at a lower gear, which is incorrect.

Comment: The clutch slips only between gears. If the clutch is slipping any other time there is something wrong with it. The transmission should never slip unless it's broken.

Comment: Yeah exactly, so how detect that 'wrong' thing? Any method to do so? Any method to calculate which gear the car, given the clutch is slipping

Comment: Are you targeting all cars? newer ones (certainly the last four years) all seem to have Gear Indication on them to aid economical driving, if you are just working with them you could interrogate that instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is not easy and is an exercise in data analysis. First you need to know the gear ratios of the car and the tire size. The tire size will allow you to calculate the RPM of the output shaft.

This is where the fun data analysis comes in. The gear ratio will converge as the clutch engages. For example if your sitting at a stop the gear ratio is infinite because speed is zero. As the clutch engages the dynamic ratio will fall but as the clutch fully engages the ratio will converge to a known value. That value will hold until the gear is changed again. The procedure repeats. The ratio will change rapidly and all over the place until the clutch reengages and then the ratio will converge to another known ratio.

The thing to note is that the ratios need to be known. This allows knowing when a gear is engaged.  If the clutch is slipping then there is no way to tell what gear your in. At most you can tell that the clutch is slipping. What you'll see is that the gear ratio will never converge to one of the known ratios.

If you are developing a product that helps people to drive a stick shift i would say you are not responsible when someone is driving a broken car. What i would suggest is some indicator that the clutch is slipping and to check your driving method or the car.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas...

You could also use the fact that typically if your vehicle speed is/was accelerating, and the RPM drops sharply without the vehicle speed dropping, then the driver shifted up.  If the RPM increases quickly and the vehicle is not accelerating, then the driver down shifted.  This would not account for dropping it in neutral.  You might be able to check if the engine speed is at idle, IACV, engine load for neutral.

I would do a range selection for each gear.  For each gear the So lets say we have a 3 speed with ratios 2.52, 1.52, 1.00 and a rear of 4.10.  These come up to overall drive ratios of 10.33, 6.23, and 4.10.  Give a tolerance just to be safe, I am using 1%.

Accelerating (so ratio will be decreasing with up shift):

x > 10.23 = first

6.19 > x < 10.23 = second

x < 6.19 = third

Decelerating (ratio will be increasing with downshift):

x > 6.27= first

4.14 > x < 6.27= second

x < 4.14 = third

Your device might be able to 'learn' the ratios.